# OpenGL 2d (orthographic) rendering for GUI, the modern way

Tags: user-interface, opengl, 2d, rendering, lwjgl

I want to render GUI components in my OpenGL program. They are still just simple textured (vbo) rectangles.
I would like to get the following things done, the right way.

1. Drawing using screen coordinates, or at least using a coordinate system that's not based on perspective-like floating points. For example: now the coordinate system is from -1f to 1f (left to right of the screen). It would be more logical to use screen/pixel coordinates.
2. If it's easy to do, I'd like that the GUI doesn't stretch when the window (viewport) resizes.

I know, previously you could do a lot using the deprecated function `glOrtho`. But since I want to do it the modern way, which is hopefully also better for performance, I don't know how to start.
After searching on the internet, I came to the conclusion that I have to use a shader. I'm not very familiar with shaders.
And another question: does performance increase when doing this using a shader?

Answer (score 2):

What you do with modern OpenGL is essentially the same as using glOrtho to setup a orthographic projection matrix: Create a transformation (matrix) that maps coordinates 1:1 into viewport coordinates and use that to transform the coordinates.

For example you could create a `vec2` uniform `viewport` and set that to the viewport width/height. Then in the vertex shader you can use that to transform your vertex pixel coordinate positions into the range [-1,1], like this

```
gl_Position = vec4(2*vpos.xy / viewport.xy - 1, 0, 1);
```

Comment: One could of course pre-calculate `vec2(2)/viewport.xy` and reduce the transformation to a simple multiply-add.

Comment: @derhass: certainly. But I aimed to illustrate the general idea of how to approach this problem. Also I'd not be surprised if OpenGL drivers' built-in GLSL compilers detect the subexpession `vec2(2)/viewport.xy` to be uniform and optimize it out. Probably not with SPIR-V or if UBOs are used, though.